# Fancybox module error messages

Tags: 7

I enabled the fancybox module, but since doing so am getting the following error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: options in _fancybox_filter_settings() (line 559 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/fancybox/fancybox.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _fancybox_filter_settings() (line 559 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/fancybox/fancybox.module).
```

Any advice as to how to fix them?

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a solution available in the following bug report filed at http://drupal.org/node/1904006

You have two possible options available.
1. There is a patch available in that post, use that.
2. Download development release, which already has that path applied in it.